# ubuntu docker openedx make dev.provision fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu, digital-ocean, openedx

I'm trying to deploy Open edX to DigitalOcean using Ubuntu. I have already set up it locally successfully with my Mac. I followed the official installation guide found here: https://github.com/edx/devstack. I went through most of the processes without a glitch until I had to run make dev.provision

I encountered a failed task:

```
Provisioning lms...
+ ./provision-lms.sh
++ apps=(lms studio)
++ ./load-db.sh edxapp
Loading the edxapp database...
Finished loading the edxapp database!
++ ./load-db.sh edxapp_csmh
Loading the edxapp_csmh database...
Finished loading the edxapp_csmh database!
++ for app in '"${apps[@]}"'
++ docker-compose up -d lms
edx.devstack.memcached is up-to-date
edx.devstack.firefox is up-to-date
edx.devstack.mongo is up-to-date
edx.devstack.elasticsearch is up-to-date
edx.devstack.mysql is up-to-date
edx.devstack.devpi is up-to-date
edx.devstack.chrome is up-to-date
edx.devstack.forum is up-to-date
edx.devstack.discovery is up-to-date
edx.devstack.lms is up-to-date
++ for app in '"${apps[@]}"'
++ docker-compose up -d studio
edx.devstack.chrome is up-to-date
edx.devstack.firefox is up-to-date
edx.devstack.mysql is up-to-date
edx.devstack.elasticsearch is up-to-date
edx.devstack.mongo is up-to-date
edx.devstack.devpi is up-to-date
edx.devstack.memcached is up-to-date
edx.devstack.discovery is up-to-date
edx.devstack.forum is up-to-date
edx.devstack.lms is up-to-date
edx.devstack.studio is up-to-date
++ docker-compose exec -T lms bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && NO_PYTHON_UNINSTALL=1 paver install_prereqs'
Build failed: Unknown task: install_prereqs
Makefile:134: recipe for target 'dev.provision.services' failed
make: *** [dev.provision.services] Error 1
```

I have used the latest version of Docker (19.03.12). What do I need to do to fix this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's not for developments, what you can do is install ubuntu native installation.